# how to change page number datatable in outside datatable with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.4 with php and jquery.
I want page numbers table with jquery but my code not Work? please helm me?

```
$(function(){

        dTable  =   $('#allProductsTbl').DataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [[1, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "همه"]],
            "responsive": true,
            "language": {
                "url": "../data/include/public/Persian.json"
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":"products/op/dt_processing.php"
        });
        dTable.order( [ 3, 'desc' ] ).draw();
        //alert('pageNumber:'+dTable.page());
       dTable.page(3).draw(false);

    });
```

Comment: in question i put it

Answer (score 5):

#### SOLUTION

Use [`page()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29) API method to set current page of the table. Note that page number is zero-based so `page(3)` opens 4<sup>th</sup> page.

For example:

```
$('#allProductsTbl').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json ) {
   var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
   api.page(3).draw(false);
});

var dTable = $('#allProductsTbl').DataTable({
   "aLengthMenu": [[1, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "همه"]],
   "responsive": true,
   "language": {
      "url": "../data/include/public/Persian.json"
   },
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax":"products/op/dt_processing.php",
   "order": [[ 3, 'desc' ]]
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bm2zvd0p/) for demonstration.

Comment: @AliNasiri, added link to demo page.

Comment: thanks you.Again does not work. i changed the my code. please help me

Comment: @AliNasiri, it doesn't work because now you have Ajax request instead. I can update the answer but why do you want to go to a specific page?

Comment: @AliNasiri, sorry, it was a typo, it's corrected now.

Comment: The "page(3) opens 4th page." help me alot, thanks.