# Jump to page functionality with Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working in JQuery Datatables Server Side Script. Every thing is working perfectly. My requirement is jump to page by implement select box in bottom, it shouuld also generate from script.

Is this functionality is present with datatable or not. Because in my database thousands of data present and i want move direct on certain page without click on page numbers on paginations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change page number datatable in outside datatable with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523581/how-to-change-page-number-datatable-in-outside-datatable-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Provided you are using jQuery datatable https://datatables.net/

You can check this plugin and use for this feature.

[jQuery Datatable Pagination](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/)

After including this plugin, you just need to add following script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#YourDataTable').dataTable( {
          "sPaginationType": "listbox"
      } );
  } );
```

Comment: Do you know how to use jQuery Plugin in  [Agular Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatable) ?